# Sections dependent on checkbox the Wordpress WP_Customize_Control

Tags: php, functions, theme-customizer

I would need to create checkbox dependent sections in wordpress customization panel if possible. They should work so that when the checkbox is checked the section "eg 1" will be shown and the section "2" will be hidden. When the checkbox is unchecked, section 2 will be shown and section 1 will be hidden. I tried adding an if command, but it only works after a page refresh.
Some ideas?
Thanks for the help.

```
        $wp_customize->add_section( 'section_checkbox', array(
                    'title' => __( 'Function Attempt', 'myTheme' ),
                    'priority' => 1,
                    'panel' => 'Page',
                    ) ) ;
                    
                    
                    
        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'checkbox_header', array( 
                    'default' => 1,
                    'sanitize_callback' => 'mytheme_chkbox_sanitization',
                    ) ) ;
                    
        $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize,
                    'checkbox_header', array(
                    'label' => __( 'Disable / Enable', 'myTheme' ),
                    'section' => 'section_checkbox',
                    'settings' => 'checkbox_header',
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    ) ) ) ;

if( get_theme_mod( 'checkbox_header','1')==true)
 {
    
        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'Enable_checkbox', array( 
                    'default' => __( '','myTheme' ),
                    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text',
                    ) ) ;

        // Add control
        $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize,
                    'Enable_checkbox', array(
                    'label' => __( 'Enable checkbox', 'myTheme' ),
                    'section' => 'section_checkbox',
                    'settings' => 'Enable_checkbox',
                    'type' => 'text',
                    ) ) ) ;
                    
} else {                      
        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'Disable_checkbox', array( 
                    'default' => __( '','myTheme' ),
                    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text',
                    ) ) ;

        // Add control
        $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize,
                    'Disable_checkbox', array(
                    'label' => __( 'Disable checkbox', 'myTheme' ),
                    'section' => 'section_checkbox',
                    'settings' => 'Disable_checkbox',
                    'type' => 'text',
                    ) ) ) ;
    }
```

Comment: what you want can never be done in pure PHP, javascript is a hard requirement since you want to modify the page without a refresh. This also means you need to register _all_ controls regardless of the checkbox, then control their visibility in javascript not PHP

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought it was easier.